# IOS/SWIFT4 - HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4])

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Does anybody know what HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4]) is? I saw a few answers on here, some say it's that the server can't process more than x requests at a time, others say its alamofire.

My script refreshes every 60 seconds and there is only one request at a time. I have alamofire installed in my project, but not using it for this refresh.

It works the first few times, but after a few minutes i get this 1005 error and then it never again afterwards unless i go to a different page and come back.

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
            if let requestURL = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/file.php") {
                var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
                urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
                let postString = "username=\(Username.text!)&password=\(Password.text!)&device_token=\(device_token)"
                urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

                let session = URLSession.shared
                let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {  (data, response, error) in
                    if let data = data {
                        do {
                            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {

                                // get lots of vars here

                                // Async Stuff
                                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                                    // do lots of things here

                                })
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print("Error: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }

                task.resume()
            }
```

The error goes like this:

TIC Read Status [2:0x60400016bac0]: 1:57

... HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4])

... finished with error - code: -1005

• I tried to add session.reset(completionHandler: { print("session ended") }) at the end
• In another post i read that i should add a header-length. but not sure if i should do that on the server or the Xcode project?
• And somehow i can't catch this error and trigger something else.

Comment: I'm getting this information, when I'm trying to make a call within the app, but doesn't have a 'valid' internet connection. Did you check, if your device has a proper internet connection?

Comment: This morning I was seeing weird stuff where -1005 can happen if you try to do a web request before the application delegate applicationDidBecomeActive fires... not sure where your code is in your stack, but if your application isn't active you might try making your web request code runs after applicationDidBecomeActive. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622956-applicationdidbecomeactive